# Is there a name for the quotient of functions where one component is an absolute function?

Tags: functions

Suppose I have the case:
$$ \frac{f(x)}{|g(x)|}$$
Is there a name for a quotient and composition of this type? Furthermore, suppose that if instead I had:
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=h(x)$$
where $h(x)$ has some syntactical definition (suppose $\tan(x)$ as one such example), would there then be a way to define the semi-absolute composition (apologies for the term; I had to coin something until I come to know the current state of the art) in terms of $h(x)$?

Comment: Did you also coin the term "composite" in this sense? I would just call it a quotient.

Comment: As would I, however in some of the reading I was doing on absolute trigonometric identities the term showed up a few term showed up a few times so I adopted it. I would be happy to edit the question to rephrase it about quotients if it were to help.

Comment: To clarify, quotient would refer to $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ but composite refers to $|g(x)|$.

http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Composite_of_two_functions
http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_value_of_sine_function

Comment: I don't thunk there is a name for such a quotient. As for the second, (don't take my for it) I would say that the only way to write the quotient is to make a piecewise defined function. For example, when g(x) is positive on an interval, the absolute value signs are redundant on such an interval. If g(x) is negative, then multiply by a negative to "undo the effect of the negative". This is the same as $-\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=h(x)$ or $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=-h(x)$

Comment: Well that's a *composition* of two functions. It's the absolute value composed with $g$.

Comment: edited to reflect that more clearly @MattSamuel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get $f(x) / |g(x)|$ just from $h(x) = f(x) / g(x)$. If $h(x) = -1$, then maybe $f(x) = 1, g(x) = -1$. Then $f(x) / |g(x)| = 1$. But what if $f(x) = - 1, g(x) = 1$? Then $f(x) / |g(x)| = -1$. So we need to know both $f$ and $g$, or rather need to know more than $f / g$.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question unfortunately. If it assists you I will try to make it a little more clear. We are assuming $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are known, and the quotient of f(x) and g(x) already has a name ( such as $\tan(x)$ then is there a symbolic representation, or naming convention, to express $\frac{f(x)}{|g(x)|}$ as some variation of  $h(x)$. We are not concerned with specific solutions, simply the nomenclature.

Comment: Okay. I know of no explicit term for it, but it's important to note this is not a property of $h$, only of $(f, g)$.